# Fallacy: for, $ p = a^x - b^x $, $x = \log_{a/b} p$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, logarithms

Question:

$$ (3+4)(3^2+4^2)(3^4+4^4)(3^8+4^8)(3^{16}+4^{16})(3^{32}+4^{32}) = 4^x - 3^x $$

Find $x$.

---

**Proposition:**

For
$$ p = a^x - b^x $$
We assume $x = \log_r p$, then.

$$ p = a^{\log_r p} - b^{\log_r p} \\ p = p^{\log_r a} - p^{\log_r b}$$
Taking log both sides yield.
$$1 = \log_r a/b \Rightarrow r = \frac ab$$

---

So, using the proposition for  $p= LHS$ of the question, we get the answer, $$x = \log_{4/3} p$$
Which is certainly not equal to the answer, which is 64. So, what is the problem with logarithm?

---

**Edit** - For $$ p = a^{\log_{r} p} - b^{\log_{r} p} $$
There can exist an unique $r$ for which the equation can statisfy the equation.  There shouldn't be a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $x = \log_{a/b} p$ is equivalent to $p = (a/b)^x = \dfrac{a^x}{b^x}$, so you're suggesting that $a^x-b^x = \dfrac{a^x}{b^x}$, which is certainly not the case in general. Your error was in the step 'taking log both sides yield'—you applied the laws of logarithms incorrectly.

Instead of trying to 'solve for $x$', a better way to approach this problem would be to multiply the left-hand side by $1$, but write $1$ as $4-3$. Then repeatedly apply the 'difference of two squares' rule. For example
$$ (4-3)(3+4) = (4-3)(4+3) = 4^2-3^2 $$
and so
$$ (4-3)(3+4)(3^2+4^2) = (4^2-3^2)(4^2+3^2) = 4^4-3^4$$
and so on.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve the problem but to find the problem in proposition. The problem was just an example case.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: I've edited my answer to identify the exact step where you made the error.

Comment: doesn't it follows all the laws of algebra correctly?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha: No. What laws of algebra are you using? There is no reason why $p = p^{\log_r a} - p^{\log_r b}$ should imply $1 = \log_r a - \log_r b$ (the latter being equal to $\log_r \frac{a}{b}$). You are assuming that $\log_p (x-y) = \log_p x - \log_p y$, which is false in general.